# Exception in thread "HazelcastSessionCleaner"

Tags: session, hazelcast, jetty-9

I have to servers with worker name of nodeA and nodeB. I have form a cluster between the two nodes using hazelcast. But when I tried disconnecting nodeB from the cluster ( by shutting down the instance) then restart it again I am having this exception after nodeB rejoins the cluster :

```
INFO: [192.168.137.108]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Connecting to /192.168.137.102:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Oct 05, 2016 11:04:07 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [192.168.137.108]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Established socket connection between /192.168.137.108:46933 and /192.168.137.102:5701
Oct 05, 2016 11:04:13 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [192.168.137.108]:5701 [dev] [3.7]

Members [2] {
        Member [192.168.137.102]:5701 - 8acfe870-0b47-49ff-9247-00a383f9487b
        Member [192.168.137.108]:5701 - baced3f3-343c-497f-ab7c-56b0b3923b58 this
}

Oct 05, 2016 11:04:15 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [192.168.137.108]:5701 [dev] [3.7] [192.168.137.108]:5701 is STARTED
2016-10-05 11:04:15.472:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor at interval 1
Exception in thread "HazelcastSessionCleaner" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:224)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:46)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:172)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryResultIterator.next(QueryResultIterator.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSessionIdManager.cleanUp(HazelcastSessionIdManager.java:223)
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSessionIdManager$1.run(HazelcastSessionIdManager.java:273)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:151)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:120)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:358)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:219)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with serialization of the session with Hazelcast Jetty plugin. The latest release ([1.0.2](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jetty-sessionmanager/releases/tag/v1.0.2)) solved the problem, so your problem can be solved by using the latest version of the plugin.

Comment: I am still encountering the error even with the latest version of the plugin.

Comment: Do you deploy the same application on both nodes? It seems the class could not be found by the other Hazelcast instance.

Comment: Both instance have the same application deployed. During first start up both of them are successfully connected to the cluster without these exception. The exception only occurs if I have stop and then start one instance while connecting to the cluster